# SSRS Format changing values

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, reportingservices-2005

In SSRS I am using an Expression to format a field as either an integer or Currency depending on an indicator I am passing in called NumFormat.

This is the expression I am using

```
=IIF(Fields!NumFormat.Value = "C", FORMAT(Fields!Antaco.Value, "C"),
FORMAT(Fields!Antaco.Value, 0))
```

The problem that I am having is that when I apply the expression it is changing the values that are being displayed (which are all `numeric(10,2)` from SQL

for instance before applying the expression I would get a value of `7319930.40` for one of the values.

that same row shows `$7319937319930.44` when the function is applied.

I have tried doing a convert to CDEC before applying the expresssion but that didn't help.

Comment: Have you tried using `"D"` instead of `0`? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y006s0cz(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: If I do that it displays as would come from SQL without doing the currency format at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you don't format the number directly. Instead, set the `Format` property of the cell to an expression such as

```
=IIF(Fields!NumFormat.Value = "C", "C", "F0")
```

The table cell can then simply be the Antaco field value.

If you need thousand separators use `N0` instead of `F0`

Comment: You're welcome. Would you kindly mark the answer as accepted as this helps other find solutions more easily.